# Using OR ( | ) in a vue component props typing

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I'm creating a Vue3 component for a customized text input that has 3 variants. Each variant expect different props, and I defined their interfaces in a separate `text-input.d.ts` file

```
export type TextInputType = "default" | "withUnit" | "addSubBtn"

export interface DefaultTextInput {
    type: "default"
    label: string
    value: string | number
}
export interface UnitTextInput {
    type: "withUnit"
    label: string
    unit: string
    value: string | number
}
export interface ButtonTextInput {
    type: "addSubBtn"
    label: string
    value: number
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I declare my props inside the Vue component, typescript doesn't recognize them properly

For instance, in this code

```jsx
<template>
...
        <div v-if="type === 'withUnit'">
          <p>{{ unit }}</p>
        </div>
...
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
...
import type {
  ButtonTextInput,
  DefaultTextInput,
  UnitTextInput,
} from './text-input';

const props = defineProps<DefaultTextInput | UnitTextInput | ButtonTextInput>();
...
</script>
```

`unit` is throwing an error saying it doesn't exist.

Is what I'm trying to do possible at all? If so, how should I modify my component or types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just go like that :

`text-input.d.ts` :

```
export type TextInputType = DefaultTextInput | UnitTextInput | ButtonTextInput;

export interface DefaultTextInput {
  type: 'default';
  label: string;
  value: string | number;
}
export interface UnitTextInput {
  type: 'withUnit';
  label: string;
  unit: string;
  value: string | number;
}
export interface ButtonTextInput {
  type: 'addSubBtn';
  label: string;
  value: number;
}
```

And in your `Vue` component :

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { type TextInputType } from './TestSO';

  const props = defineProps<TextInputType>();
</script>
<template>
  <div v-if="props.type === 'withUnit'">
    <p>{{ props.unit }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

When using the  syntax in a `Vue` component with `TypeScript`, Vue automatically deconstructs the props to make them directly accessible in the template, without needing to prefix them with props. However, this can sometimes lead to errors. typing with TypeScript, especially when working with optional props.

In this case, Typescript normally doesn't throw an error, and don't forget the `props` before the `.unit` to help Typescript find it.

Hope it helps you ! :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sadly, `unit` is till not being picked up, even when adding `props.` in front of it. The code suggestion when I write `props.` only suggest the 3 basic shared properties. I tried restarting the IDE and the TS-plugin, but no changes

Comment: You also need to define your props that way : `const props = defineProps<TextInputType>();` With TextInputType being `export type TextInputType = DefaultTextInput | UnitTextInput | ButtonTextInput;
`

Comment: Also what's your version of `Typscript` ?

Comment: Yep, I did the edit in the `.d.ts` file and the import. Typescript version is `typescript@5.3.3`

Comment: I've bumped it to 5.4.2, but no changes

Comment: Okay, I added `props.` in front of `type` in the `if` condition just above `unit` and it worked. Thank you very much for your help, I'll mark it as resolved